# Create a new object having the pair key and value from TextInput

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'd like to create a new object. The key and value of the new object are the inputs from `TextInput`. Below please see my code. Obviously when I hit submit, the new object will always take the string *'key'* as its key and not the value that I input. How do I fix it? Thank you.

```
state = {
 list: [{key1:1},{key2:2}],
 key:'',
 value:0,
}
_onSubmit = () =>{
 let {list,key,value} = this.state;
 let myList = [...list];
 let newProp = {};
 newProp.key = value;
 myList.push(newProp);
 this.setState({list: myList});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is newProp[key] = value;

Comment: @ThanhPham Glad I could help!  Mark it answered when you get a chance.